# What does 'Tex-master' mean?

Tags: auctex

I use AUCTeX. AUCTeX has inserted a comment at the end of my `test4.tex` file that reads:

```
%%% TeX-master: "test3"
```

What does it mean?

When I try to compile and pdf-print `test4.tex`, the document that gets opened is `test3.pdf`. Why?

Comment: It says “`C-c C-c` runs LaTeX on `test3.tex` instead of the file corresponding to the current buffer”. Useful if you are working on a subfile and want to compile the main document, instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The tex  master tells emacs which document to pass to latex.

So you can have a section or even just a single equation in a file that is `\input` into your master document, and when you use `C-c C-c` or any other command that requires a full document, then the master document will be run.

Comment: Whenever I C-c C-c a new document, AUCTeX asks what the master document should be. If I understand you correctly, this means that I should normally choose the document that I am working on, right?

Comment: @EvanAad it should default to that, ie if you just hit return it will do the right thing.

Comment: OK. Here's something I don't understand. When I create a new .tex document it asks me to provide a master file, but it doesn't give me as a default the file that I'm creating; instead it gives as default the currently open .tex document. Is this how it's supposed to act?

Comment: Your settings must be different as for single file documents I don't have the comment at all, but the behaviour you suggest isn't unreasonable if you think of a model where your master document is "thesis.tex" for 3 years but during that time you want to open many other files for individual sections. However this is emacs any behaviour is configurable if you don't like it;-)

Comment: @EvanAad - You can customize `TeX-master`, check [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dmaster-2) for options.